# How can I add a column that increments on another column in same table?

Tags: mysql, increment

I have a table with a column called "IP", and I would like to create another column in the same table "YTD_IP" which would give the cumulative year-to-date sum of "IP" (innings pitched) for any given game in a year reflecting the sum of innings pitched in games (rows/events) that preceded it in the same season.  Once there is a change in year, I'd like the sum to start at 0 again.

Here is a sample of data of columns "PIT_ID", "YEAR_ID", "IP", and what I'd like to see the "YTD_IP" column look like:

```
Pit_ID  YEAR_ID  IP      YTD_IP
aased001      1977  9.0000    9
aased001      1977  9.0000    18
aased001      1977  7.0000    25
aased001      1977  5.0000    30
aased001      1977  6.3333    36.3333
aased001      1977  6.3333    42.6666
aased001      1977  7.0000    49.6666
aased001      1977  6.0000    55.6666
aased001      1977  9.0000    64.6666
aased001      1977  9.0000    73.6666
aased001      1977  5.0000    78.6666
aased001      1977  6.3333    84.9999
aased001      1977  7.3333    92.3333
aased001      1978  4.3333     4.3333
aased001      1978  7.0000    11.3333
aased001      1978  6.3333    17.6666
aased001      1978  3.3333    20.9999
```

I've put together the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ADD COLUMN YTD_IP VARCHAR(255);
    SET YTD_IP:= 0;
    SELECT a.IP,  b.YEAR_ID
      IF(@prevYEAR_ID != YEAR_ID,IP,@YTD_IP+IP) AS IP,
      @prevYEAR_ID=YEAR_ID
    FROM starting_pitcher_game_log
```

But it's not right as it gets the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(@prevYEAR_ID != YEAR_ID,IP,@YTD_IP+IP) AS IP,
          @prevYEAR_ID=YEAR_ID
' at line 2
```

Is there a way to make sure that it accommodates future games that will be played?

Any help would go a long way.

[screen shot of full table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMnbC.png)

Hi Darwin,

Can you share code that could work for a temporarily invoked column as well as code for a permanent one that could create a cumulative sum field? In particular, I would like to create another column in a table called "YTD_IP" which would give the cumulative year-to-date sum of "IP" (innings pitched) from the beginning of a season up to any given game in that season reflecting the sum of innings pitched by a given pitcher in games (rows/events) that preceded the given game + the innings pitched in that game.  Once there is a change in season, I'd like the sum to start at 0 again.

Thank you in advances in  for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice to you is, Don't do this. Storing information that can be derived from other information in the database is generally considered very poor design, and attempting to rely on the order of the rows *in the database* is a sure path to madness.

Here's a first pass at normalizing your table:

```
-- Table: teams

-- DROP TABLE teams;

CREATE TABLE teams
(
  team_id character(3) primary key,
  team_name varchar(255),
  team_city varchar(255)
) engine=innodb;

-- Table: starting_pitchers_game_log

-- DROP TABLE starting_pitchers_game_log;

CREATE TABLE starting_pitchers_game_log
(
  pitcher_id character(10) NOT NULL,
  game_date date NOT NULL,
  opposing_team character(3),
  game_seq integer NOT NULL,
  outcome character(1),
  innings_pitched real,
  bfp integer,
  hits integer,
  runs integer,
  errors integer,
  homeruns integer,
  bb integer,
  k integer,
  ibb integer,
  hbp integer,
  wp integer,
  balks integer,
  CONSTRAINT starting_pitcher_log_pk
      PRIMARY KEY (pitcher_id , game_date , game_seq ),
  CONSTRAINT team_fk FOREIGN KEY (opposing_team)
      REFERENCES teams (team_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
) engine=innodb;
```

(I don't follow baseball, so I could only guess at some of the column names.) Note that the `year_id`, `month_id` and `day_id` columns are gone, as those values can be recreated from the `game_date` column as I indicated in the comments. Also your `game_id` column is gone; this can be recreated from concatenating `opposing_team`, `game_date` and `game_seq` (which I presume is to account for double-headers &c.) I've also converted `W` and `L` into a single column intended to hold the values "W" (win), "L" (loss), and "T" (tie).

The `teams` table provides a lookup table for the 3-char team ids. It can be expanded to hold any other team data you want. (Note it is meant to describe the team *itself;* team *activities* would go in another table.)

To answer your question about the "constraint" clauses, the first one (`CONSTRAINT starting_pitcher_log_pk` and the indented line below it) specifies that the concatenation of those three columns serves as the primary unique identifier for each row in the table. The second one (`CONSTRAINT team_fk FOREIGN KEY (opposing_team)` and the indented lines below it) means that for a value to be placed in the `opposing_team` column it *must already exist* in the `teams.team_id` column; you can't play against a team that doesn't exist.

Now to work on actually answering your original question. The best solution I could come up with on MySQL was a scratch table and a stored procedure, as follows:

```
-- Table: ip_subtotal

-- DROP TABLE ip_subtotal;

CREATE TABLE ip_subtotal
(
  pitcher_id char(10) NOT NULL,
  game_date date NOT NULL,
  game_seq int(11) NOT NULL,
  innings_pitched double,
  ip_total double DEFAULT '0.0',
  CONSTRAINT ip_subtotal_pk
      PRIMARY KEY (pitcher_id , game_date , game_seq )
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the stored procedure:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE accumulate_innings()
BEGIN
    DECLARE pit_id CHAR(10);
    DECLARE gdate DATE;
    DECLARE seq INT;
    DECLARE in_pit REAL;
    DECLARE accum REAL;
    DECLARE prev_year YEAR(4);
    DECLARE end_of_cursor BOOLEAN;

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq, innings_pitched
            FROM ip_subtotal
            ORDER BY pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

    TRUNCATE TABLE ip_subtotal;
    INSERT INTO ip_subtotal
        SELECT pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq, innings_pitched, 0.0
            FROM starting_pitchers_game_log;

    SET prev_year := 0;
    OPEN c1;

    fetch_loop: LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq, in_pit;
        IF end_of_cursor THEN
            LEAVE fetch_loop;
        END IF;
        IF YEAR(gdate) != prev_year THEN
            SET accum := 0.0;
            SET prev_year := YEAR(gdate);
        END IF;
        SET accum := accum + in_pit;
        UPDATE ip_subtotal
            SET ip_total = accum
            WHERE pitcher_id = pit_id
              AND game_date = gdate
              AND game_seq = seq;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END
```

This procedure clears out the table `ip_subtotal`, populates it from the main table, then rolls up the running total for innings pitched. It also uses a simple control-break to reset the accumulator at the start of the year. After you've run the procedure by executing

```
CALL accumulate_innings();
```

you can query the `ip_subtotal` table or join it back to the `starting_pitchers_game_log` table as desired.

The procedure could also be extended to accept a start and end date; I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Hope this helps; it was interesting and forced me to learn a little MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your cautionary thoughts.  Can you please clarify a few things about what you said?  I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the PIT_ID column was derived from another column in the same table which is the same as a column in another table I have called GAME_ID.  So, each PIT_ID entry/value is yoked to a particular GAME_ID file that specifies the date of the game and the team that he played against--This part makes it so that the values in the column that I'm trying to create would not rely simply on a current sort order but on the yoked GAME_ID file that goes with it.

Comment: To clarify,  I meant to say that every PIT_ID value is yoked to a unique value (date) in another column called "GAME_ID" in the same table.

Comment: Can you post a full layout for this table?

Comment: I added a link to a screen shot of the table in the main post at the bottom.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would you be averse to a major overhaul and normalization of this table? I see a lot of room for optimization that would simplify it, shrink it, and avoid the work to keep several columns consistent with each other.

Comment: Not at all.   That would be ideal,  as long as there was a way to keep separate columns for these variables, e.g., day,  date,  month,  year.  Not sure how it would affect what you plan to propose,  but I plan to add more columns to reflect different baseball statistics, and then to analyze the data in R and/or SPSS.  One barrier in creating these tables has been that my MySQL coding skills are extremely limited.   Because I'm so slow due to my lacking skills,  I've only been able to glean enough information on quick and dirty approaches discussed here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I was specifically going to drop the extra date-related columns, since you can extract those columns at query time eg. `SELECT game_date, YEAR(game_date) AS game_year, MONTH(game_date) AS game_month, DAYNAME(game_date) as game_day FROM game_log;`  The idea is that you don't need to *keep* these columns to *have* them.

Comment: Darwin, Sounds like an efficient way to have access to this data without having it take up space/resources in the table when not in use...can you or anyone provide feedback related to the question in the original post which was about how to create an incementing/cumulative sum column with incrementing values based on that of another column's values?

Comment: I'm working on that part now. The short version is to have a stored procedure that queries the table and adds the running total column in a temporary table. It also occurs to me that tools like r or SPSS should be able to do this themselves, but that may not meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Please see edited main post above.

Comment: Try submitting your edit again, only make it on the original question.

Comment: Darwin,  What a great surprise to get something this sophisticated to accomplish this goal instead of at best a much cruder approach that would have taken me 10x the amount of time.  Thank you for this introduction to the merits and utility of procedures, declarations, loops, temporary columns in service of placing a premium on efficiency when working with a lot of data like this. It's simply excellent!  I will now try to tweak this code to accomplish creating season-to-date ERA and WHIP for these pitchers.  This will be extremely useful!  Thank you again.

Comment: My pleasure. I enjoy this sort of programming exercise.

Comment: Darwin, so I was able to create a table for innings_pitched that includes a   column for cumulative sum of innings pitched using your code to create the table and code to create a procedure to supply values to that table.  Then, I successfully created another table for cumulative sum of earned runs by modifying your table and procedure code.  However, it occurred to me that it might be more efficient and data less scattered if I incorporated both innings pitched and earned runs into the same table.  However, it doesn't work--I updated post above with the code I used-can you help?

Comment: Lee, I've rejected your update to this thread because I believe the problems you're having should be addressed as a separate question. Please open a new question and I shall be happy to provide what assistance I can.

Comment: Oh, yeah, remember to come back here and link to the new question so I get notified of it.

Comment: Darwin, Here is the link to the site with the newly posted question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950478/how-can-i-combine-two-procedures-in-one-to-populate-one-table-rather-than-each-o

Comment: Darwin, please see the following link for a question related to the stored procedure method (and the create table method) of creating columns for starting_pitcher_stats.  I have a question about which method is accurate, as both approaches produce different values for the rows of the created field.  I hope you can help.  Thank you in advance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677152/which-code-is-correct-for-creating-an-incrementing-column-in-mysql-in-sequel-pro