# How can I add a column to a work table using a new stored procedure

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add a column to a work table using a new procedure, one that is different from the procedure I used to populate the columns already in the work table.  I'm not sure if it would be more efficient and resources-conserving to do it this way or by adding on to the original procedure I used to populate the columns/values that are already in the table.  In any case, here is the code for a separate procedure to add this column.  The column is called "starter_rest" and is expressed as the difference between the date value in field "Game_Date" and the previous value in that field/column.

Here is the code I'm using which is giving me an error.

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS accumulate_starter_rest()

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE PROCEDURE accumulate_starter_rest()
BEGIN
        DECLARE pit_id VARCHAR(8);
        DECLARE gdate DATE;
        DECLARE prev_date DATE;
        DECLARE seq INT;
        DECLARE strt_rst REAL;
        DECLARE prev_year YEAR(4);
        DECLARE end_of_cursor BOOLEAN;

        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
          SELECT starter_rest
            FROM ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1
            ORDER BY Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date, Game_Number;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
          SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

        TRUNCATE TABLE ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1;
        INSERT INTO ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1 (starter_rest)
        SELECT starter_rest
            FROM ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1;

        SET end_of_cursor := FALSE;
        SET prev_year := 0;

        OPEN c1;

        fetch_loop: LOOP
          FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, prev_date, seq, strt_rst;
          IF end_of_cursor THEN
            LEAVE fetch_loop;
          END IF;
          IF YEAR(gdate) != prev_year THEN
            SET strt_rst := 0;
            SET prev_year := YEAR(gdate);
          END IF;
          SET strt_rst := gdate - prev_date;
          END IF;
          UPDATE TABLE ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1
          SET starter_rest = strt_rst
              WHERE Starting_Pitcher = pit_id
                AND Game_Date = gdate
                AND Game_Number = seq;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c1;
      END

      $$
```

Here is the error I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF;
          UPDATE TABLE ip_ER_ERA_subtotal_1
          SET starter_rest = str' at line 39
```

Here is the screen shot of the table with the column I'm trying to populate already created and with "NULL" values.

Thank you in advance for any help.

update:

```
ALTER TABLE retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log ADD COLUMN starter_rest INT;
UPDATE retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log AS b,
retrosheet.game AS g
SELECT @prev as previous,
 Game_Date
FROM retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log
SET b. starter_rest = Game_date-@prev
WHERE b.`Game_ID` = g.`GAME_ID`
```

getting error:

```
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @prev as previous,
 Game_Date
FROM retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log
S' at line 3
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: Here's the edited table to set 0 value for starter_rest at the beginning of a new year:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS starting_pitcher_stats_rest_time;

DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE starting_pitcher_stats_rest_time()

      BEGIN
        DECLARE pit_id CHAR(10);
        DECLARE gdate DATE;
        DECLARE seq INT;
        DECLARE prev_date DATE;
        DECLARE rest_days INT;
        DECLARE prev_year YEAR(4);
        DECLARE end_of_cursor BOOLEAN;

        DECLARE no_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02';

        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
          SELECT Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date, Game_Number
            FROM starting_pitcher_stats
            ORDER BY Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date, Game_Number;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
          SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR no_table
        BEGIN
          SIGNAL no_table
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Work table not initialized. Please call pitcher_stats_reset() before continuing",
            MYSQL_ERRNO = 1146;
        END;

        SET prev_date := 0;
        SET end_of_cursor := FALSE;

        OPEN c1;
        fetch_loop: LOOP
          FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq;
          IF end_of_cursor THEN
            LEAVE fetch_loop;
          END IF;

          IF YEAR(gdate) != prev_year THEN
            SET rest_days := 0;
            SET prev_date := 0;
            SET gdate := 0;
            SET prev_year := YEAR(gdate);
          END IF;

          IF prev_date = 0 THEN
            SET rest_days := 0;
          ELSE
            SET rest_days := DATEDIFF(gdate, prev_date);
          END IF;
          SET prev_date := gdate;

          UPDATE starting_pitcher_stats
            SET starter_rest = rest_days
            WHERE Starting_Pitcher = pit_id
              AND Game_Date = gdate
              AND Game_Number = seq;

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE c1;

      END
    $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a screenshot of the table with showing the excessive value for starter rest at the beginning of a new season.  Ideally, it would just reset to 0:

[image]

Any help would be great.  By the way, Darwin, thank you--Your help has been great!

Comment: It seems to me unlikely that you would want to use a sproc to edit a table structure.

Comment: Ok Strawberry,  can you sugget how to do it?

Comment: My point is that editing a table is such a rare activity that you'd probably just do it manually

Comment: Ok,  well I am planning on adding many more variables/fields to the table one by one as I figure out how to derive them from fields in other columns of tables.  I'll then be calling up many of them at once in SPSS and R to do analyses on them.  So my thinking was to do everything I can on the front end to reduce processing time/resources utilization to access these variables before I actually do the analyses.  Can you please share what the manual method of doing this is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should look again at normalisation - if you remain of the opinion that an RDBMS is the right solution.

Comment: I'm seeing why normalisation is important...There are a few reasons I'm using a relational database like MySQL.  The first is that the original/raw data came in the format of MySQL, so I've been using data in this environment out of convenience. The second is that after I analyze this data, I'll use MySQL to test the models I arrived at from analyzing it on future games-- I'll use queries reflecting these models in MySQL to tell me which games scheduled in the future will apply, and test the models, and to the extent they are not, tweak them to optimize them.  Any suggestions?

Comment: please see above attempt at manually entering code.  Getting errors.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I think you're confusing data storage and data display.

Comment: Ah.... How so? Would you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Well, typically, you might store pitcher_name and date_played, say. Then you would use those two bits of information to derive the stats, but you wouldn't necessarily store the stats in a table. Instead, you might store them in a view, or just execute a query at run time for display in some kind of presentation layer (e.g. PHP). I don't know baseball, so I'll take the example of soccer - oh, here's one someone made earlier http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=804 . It shows stored data (match results) and derived data (played, won, lost, drawn, etc.)

Comment: Hello, Lee. Two questions: is the `starter_rest` data *dependent* on the ERA data computed by the other procedure, and will the `starter_rest` data *be used at the same time as* the ERA data?

Comment: Strawberry,  yes storing only the essential variables (e.g., pitcher name, date of game)  In a table and using those variables to order the stats data makes sense.  But the stats aren't actually extracted from those 2 variables.  Isn't PHP used for displaying data on a website? (I am using sequel pro server but only as a GUI on my computer to visualize my data on the same computer.)   But can I actually access the data for analysis when they are stored in a view or when they are executed from a query at run time for display in PHP?

Comment: Hi Darwin, the starter_rest data is not dependent on the ERA data the way it is on Game_Date and starting_pitcher.  But I will likely use both variables in queries at the same time as I think both likely interact to determine outcome of a game.   Whether I use them together will ultimately depend on the outcome of thee analyses.

Comment: Can `starter_rest` be measured in whole days, or do you need to measure it in hours?

Comment: Darwin,  actually,  now that I think about it,  starter rest will be more accurate if it is expressed in hours--It's just that I never thought it could be expressed in terms of hours. But I believe it can be because I have a field in one of my tables for game start time,  expressed in terms of hours and minutes. I'm thinking that calculating it to the nearest hour would require Game_start_time to be ORDERed by PITCHER_ID and Game_Date as well as GROUPED with those two...

Comment: Now I think about it, I'm not sure there's enough data to measure it in hours. We'd need to know both the time the pitcher started and the time he retired. I'll do it in days, and you can change it to hours in Version 2. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question, and its answer, build upon the answers to [How can I combine two procedures in one to populate one table rather than each of the two procedures populating it's own table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950478/how-can-i-combine-two-procedures-in-one-to-populate-one-table-rather-than-each-o) and [How can I add a column that increments on another column in same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860342/how-can-i-add-a-column-that-increments-on-another-column-in-same-table), and the answer to this question necessitates minor changes to the answer to the previous two, which I shall note when appropriate.

Since the "pitcher rest period" and "earned runs average" calculations are independent of each other, I recommend a separate procedure for each. However, since the results of the two procedures will often be used together, I recommend a common scratch table for the calculations, and suggest [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) the creation and population of that scratch table into a third procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

-- DROP PROCEDURE pitcher_stats_reset $$

CREATE PROCEDURE pitcher_stats_reset()
BEGIN
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS pitcher_stats_temp;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pitcher_stats_temp
  (
    pitcher_id      char(10)    NOT NULL,
    game_date       date        NOT NULL,
    game_seq        int         NOT NULL,
    innings_pitched double      DEFAULT 0.0,
    ip_total        double      DEFAULT 0.0,
    earned_runs     INT         DEFAULT 0,
    er_total        INT         DEFAULT 0,
    std_era         DOUBLE      DEFAULT 0.0,
    starter_rest    INT         DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT pitcher_stats_temp_pk
      PRIMARY KEY (pitcher_id , game_date , game_seq )
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

  INSERT INTO pitcher_stats_temp
        (pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq, innings_pitched, earned_runs)
      SELECT pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq,
          IFNULL(innings_pitched, 0),  -- replace NULL with 0, if
          IFNULL(runs, 0)              --   column not initialized
        FROM starting_pitchers_game_log;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The previous version used a normal, persistent table because I was not yet familiar with MySQL's handling of temporary tables. A temporary table is automatically dropped when the user logs off, reclaiming the space used for derived data which can be regenerated at need. Dropping and recreating the table is equivalent to `TRUNCATE`ing (except that the table need not exist beforehand) which in turn is much faster than an unconditional `DELETE`, according to the MySQL docs. I've made appropriate annotated changes to the [earned-runs-average procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950478/how-can-i-combine-two-procedures-in-one-to-populate-one-table-rather-than-each-o) as well.

The procedure to calculate pitchers' resting time once again follows the standard "control-break" idiom. Note that we read the first record and set up the control fields once before entering the loop, then within the loop we test for our exit condition, process the "current" record, read the "next" record, and loop.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pitcher_stats_rest_time;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE pitcher_stats_rest_time()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE pit_id          CHAR(10);
    DECLARE prev_pit        CHAR(10);
    DECLARE gdate           DATE;
    DECLARE seq             INT;
    DECLARE prev_date       DATE;
    DECLARE rest_days       INT;
    DECLARE end_of_cursor   BOOLEAN;

    DECLARE no_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02';

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq
        FROM pitcher_stats_temp
        ORDER BY pitcher_id, game_date, game_seq;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
      SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR no_table
    BEGIN
      SIGNAL no_table
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Work table not initialized. Please call pitcher_stats_reset() before continuing",
        MYSQL_ERRNO = 1146;
    END;

    SET end_of_cursor := FALSE;

    -- Read first record and initialize control fields
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq;
    SET prev_date := 0;
    SET prev_pit := pit_id;

    fetch_loop: LOOP
      -- Test for end-of-cursor
      IF end_of_cursor THEN
        LEAVE fetch_loop;
      END IF;

      -- Test for change in control fields. If the pitcher changes,
      --  fake a change in the year to trigger the break.
      IF pit_id != prev_pit THEN
        SET prev_date := 0;
      END IF;

      IF YEAR(prev_date) = YEAR(gdate) THEN
        SET rest_days := DATEDIFF(gdate, prev_date);
      ELSE
        SET rest_days := 0;
      END IF;

      UPDATE pitcher_stats_temp
        SET starter_rest = rest_days
        WHERE pitcher_id = pit_id
          AND game_date = gdate
          AND game_seq = seq;

      -- After processing record, update control fields
      SET prev_date := gdate;
      SET prev_pit := pit_id;

      -- Read next record and repeat
      FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;

  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In use, `pitcher_stats_reset()` is called first, to initialize the work table. Once that is done, `pitcher_stats_era()` and `pitcher_stats_rest_time()` may be called repeatedly in any order. If `pitcher_stats_reset()` is not called first, the other two procedures will issue a polite reminder to do so.

Comment: Darwin, nice!I like you're idea of temporary tables called up when needed and an initializing procedure to call up the work tables before running procedures that populate temp table with data.  After changing "runs" to "earned_runs" in 2nd IFNULL statement of CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE procedure, that procedure ran fine.  So did the other two after removing the blocked off text from the pitcher_stats_era procedure (because blocked off text gave an error).  But, for some reason the table "pitcher_stats_temp" does not appear on the list of tables even after the procedures are run in correct order.

Comment: Temporary tables don't show up under `SHOW TABLES`. I fear I don't know how to list temporary tables in MySQL, but the ERA and Pitcher Rest procedures will both politely remind you if the temporary table hasn't been created.

Comment: Wow, is there a way of visualizing the contents of the tables?  Otherwise how can you make sure that the table creation process created the right contents? Or even remember what Fields have already been created so that you don't duplicate work already done?

Comment: You can still `DESCRIBE` the table and `SELECT` from it. I'm just not sure how one would *list the names* of one's temporary tables.

Comment: Hi Darwin, for the purposes of visualizing the values that were populating the columns of the pitcher_stats table I repeated the process without the temporary tables.  I'm realizing that for "starter_rest", the values have to reset to 0 at the start of a new season(year) for every "Starting_Pitcher", and each time there's a new "Starting_Pitcher".  Please see above attempt adding code to starter rest procedure to reset the values to 0 at the start of a new year.

Comment: I had overlooked that. I've rewritten the loop to use standard control-break idiom, with breaks on pitcher ID and game year.

Comment: Darwin, thank you for editing it and for annotations.  What does == mean and why must we fake a year change to trigger starting at 0 again? I get the following error: [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== YEAR(gdate) THEN
        SET rest_days := DATEDIFF(gdate, prev_date);   
      E' at line 48

Comment: Faking a change of year is just a convenient way of making sure a new pitcher starts out from 0; we want the same behaviour as if the year had changed, so we "make" the year change to provoke that behaviour. As for `==`, that's a bit of C syntax that got in there by mistake. ;)

Comment: Hi  Darwin,I have a new dilemma that I wonder if you can help me with regarding using stored function to call up value into a new column in starting_pitcher_stats table.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538685/need-help-adding-column-to-one-table-using-function-that-does-arithmetic-functio